# migrating code including files within gitignore

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, migration, database-migration

Problem: Migrating code between servers which has many 'secure files' that contain sensitive login information and have been gitignored due to their sensitivity. I can successfully conduct a git clone to retrieve code from git but I am looking for a possible solution to migrate code that is ignored within the git repository.

As a follow-up, I am cloning my Git repository upon booting up an aws ec2 instance but I would also like to 'clone' files that are being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the 'secure' files in an S3 bucket that has versions, encryption and auditing enabled. Give your servers access to the S3 bucket via IAM roles. Then you can run `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` commands on your servers to retrieve the files when needed.

For more information about AWS S3 security, view the "Security" section of [the FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/).